# jQuery slider carousel with multiple images (prev/next) in slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, carousel

I am looking for someone to suggest a good jQuery carousel plugin with thumbnails below and larger version of those thumbnails above it.
There are many jQuery carousels with an option for slideshow along with thumbnails, but what I need is,
3 images to be visible in the slideshow. Prev image of "current slide" and Next image of "current slide". So when the user clicks a thumbnail, it also slides the above slideshow with 3 images.
[image]

Any ideas how to implement with an existing jquery carousel plugin?
I guess, a multiple carousel with "sync" feature? Anything else?

I came across FlexSlider and it has option for Slideshow with thumbnail carousel. [FlexSlider with thumbnail carousel](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html) It automatically adds a "flex-active-slide" to the slideshow image. I decided to make visible the prev and next images depending on the "flex-active-slide", so it shows 3 images in 1 scroll. But, when I change the width of each slideshow, "flex-active-slide" is not added. This makes it difficult to determine the prev/next slide which I want to show along-with. I have tried other carousels like CarouFredsel, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: This isn't a website to ask people how to solve "big" problems. Particularly those which have been solved many times before. If you've made any attempts yourself and you get stuck, fine. But people aren't here to do your work for you.

Comment: I am not asking to create a plugin for me. I have seen sliders like this on web before, so I thought someone might have come across a situation like this.

Comment: OK, **IF** you have Google'd the question before you posted on SO, then please rephrase it to something like "I was looking for someone to suggest a good jQuery carousel plugin which can cope with 3 active images simultaneously" rather than "I need a carousel plugin"

Comment: Poor English, my bad.

Comment: No problem :) - we get a lot of requests on this site which are of very poor quality and never get attention as a result - finally, you mention that there are "a lot of carousel plugins", but could you list some which you've already looked at so that people can know where you're up to and where you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks +1 for improving your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Swiper](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper) is the closest implementation for such a use-case.
http://idangero.us/swiper/

Answer (score 0):

I found one which seems to  be what you're looking for, except the smaller thumbnails are above the main-image as-opposed to below by default so you may have to modify the code slightly.

**Found out more here:**

[Markup page](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/20/responsive-image-gallery/)
[Demo](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/)